# How to convert result string to column database

Tags: sql

I have a question:
This query

```
SELECT 'ID_' + ISNULL (cast (fields.ID AS VARCHAR), '') AS FIELD_ID
FROM MYTABLE fields
WHERE fields.id = 1
```

ID_1 returns me as a string, I need to use that ID_1 in another query that is a column in the table that I need to find its value
the complete query would be like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) (SELECT 'ID_' + ISNULL (cast (fields.ID AS VARCHAR), '') AS FIELD_ID
                FROM MYTABLE fields
                WHERE fields.id = 1) as value
FROM MYTABLE2
```

Comment: _fields_ is a very confusing table alias...

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: You need a dynamic query to generate queries with condition specific fields

Comment: what RDMS are you using?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and you are using invalid standard SQL). Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 0):

IS this where you are going with it?

```
select * from targettable
join (

    SELECT 'ID_' + ISNULL (cast (fields.ID AS VARCHAR), '') AS FIELD_ID
    FROM MYTABLE fields
    WHERE fields.id = 1

) a
on targettable.FIELD_ID = a.FIELD_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dynamic SQL`

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @Column nvarchar(1000)

SET  @Column = SELECT TOP 1 'ID_' + ISNULL (CAST(fields.ID AS VARCHAR), '') 
               FROM MYTABLE 
               WHERE fields.id = 1
SET @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 1' + @Column + ' FROM MYTABLE2'     
EXEC (@SQL)
```